# Fine Lines Cycles Render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders

[image]

I have been interested in high-tech HUD looking renders in Blender. Many of the HUD graphics that I see are pushing the limits of how small text can be while still remaining legible. They push the limits of how thin lines can be on the traditional 1080p monitor. It's pleasing to see lines that may only be a pixel in width.

The problem is that most of the HUD that I see out there was made in Adobe, and probably uses less GPU than our lovely Cycles ray tracing. For example, use a wireframe mod with a very thin wireframe, only to find that it's choppy or requires huge sample-count. If that wireframe was shaded with emission shader, it would add tons of noise to the scene because of the nature of small emitters.

So is there a way to balance the power of Cycles with the fine lines of your everyday thin vectors? Even better, with glare?

The render shown has a tiny wireframe mod thickness of .0005 and an emission shader. It also has a glare in the compositor which doesn't show up well at these thicknesses. Notice that the line breaks. This rendered 128 Cycles at 4.39 seconds on 3090 RTX. Compressed for stackexchange upload reqs.

Comment: Sounds like the kind of thing EEVEE would excel at. Any reason to force use Cycles?

Comment: Cycles generally gives better renders than EEVEE, but perhaps we're talking about a second view layer, which is rendered in EEVEE with glare and alpha over the first layer. EVEE. Not a terrible solution, but even the viewport shading doesn't 'render' lines, they simply appear as lines that don't have any noise or what not.